# Help with connect / disconnect script

Tags: wifi, script

Very noob to Pi programming but am tech savvy.
Can somebody help with the 2 questions below:

1) How to I go about setting a script to run boot

2) Can you also help with a script to do the following:
A) Disconnect from all WIFI (outstanding)
B) monitor for specific SSID and connect (outstanding)
C) On finding specific SSID login and transfer files (complete)
D) once file transfer complete disconnect (complete)
E) connect to SSID 2 (outstanding)
F) transfer files (complete)
G) Disconnect and sleep until x (outstanding)

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here.

Comment: How to run your script on boot is explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47695/how-to-write-startup-script-for-systemd).